# The type 'EMail' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, .net, google-data-api

I getting the following error:

```
Error   1   The type 'Google.GData.Extensions.EMail' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Google.GData.Extensions, Version=1.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0b4c5df2ebf20876'
```

my code:

```
using Google.Contacts;
using Google.GData;
using Google.GData.Contacts;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;

   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RequestSettings settings = new RequestSettings("test app", "mail", "pass");
            settings.AutoPaging = true;
            ContactsRequest contacts = new ContactsRequest(settings);
            Feed<Contact> list = contacts.GetContacts();

            foreach (Contact contact in list.Entries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(contact.Emails);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }
```

how I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding a reference to assembly 'Google.GData.Extensions, Version=1.9.0.0'? (That specific assembly and version?)

Comment: Did you try adding the reference at the project level by clicking on References and adding it that way opposed to adding it at the header with the "using" clause..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed

I reinstall the `google data api sdk` do I did new project and works fine now.